# How to make a data dependent format for a date column [displaytag]?

Tags: jsp, displaytag

In a table using the displaytag library on a JSP page like this:

```
<display:table id="foo" name="request.foo">
    ...
    <display:column
        title="Some date"
        format="${empty request.theDates[foo_rowNum-1]?'':'{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}'}"
        value="${request.theDates[foo_rowNum-1]}" />
    ...
</display:table>
```

the problem is, that the *format* attribute is evaluated only once. That is, the same computed value is used for all rows, instead of depending on the data, as intended.

So if the first date is *null*, the empty format string (which means "use default format") will be used for all of the rows. If the first date is not *null*, the specified format will be used for all rows. This is a problem, because if the date in some row is *null*, the formatter will log an ERROR. So the logs will fill up with errors, that really aren't (obscuring real errors).

So the question is: how to specify a custom format for the date column, that will work and will not log errors for empty (*null*) dates? Use a decorator? Maybe some JSP function?

Comment: Yes, use a decorator.

Comment: @AlanHay That's what I did. Thanks.